# Is new(&*p) double; a no-op. Does therefore uninitialized_default_construct becomes no-op as well?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, placement-new, no-op

The STL documentation says that the (1) [`uninitialized_default_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_default_construct) calls `::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*p))) Value;`.

The only difference with (2) [`uninitialized_value_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct) is that the later calls, `::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*p))) Value();`. (note the **`()`**)

**I wonder what is the practical difference for both built-in types and non-trivial types.**

For built-ins, it seems to me that the second (2) will do value initialization, i.e. setting the value to zero while the first (1) will be a no-op (leaving the value uninitialized.)

For non-trivial types (2) will call the default constructors. What it is not clear to me is what (1) will do for non-trivial types. Will also call the default constructor? will it be also a no-op as long as `T::T() = default` and it is no-op and leave the element in a partially formed state if the the class was designed to be so?

**What also confuses me is why the STL containers will always use `uninitialized_value_construct` although it would have been more consistent to call `uninitialized_default_construct` when possible.**

For example `std::vector<double>(100)` -> should call `uninitialized_default_construct` while the current behavior could have been mimicked with `std::vector<double>(100, {})` or `std::vector<double>(100, double{})`.

**Is this because the concept of `uninitialized_default_construct` didn't exists in the initial version of STL? or simply there is no easy way to pass the information down to the constructor of the the container?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What also confuses me is why the STL containers will always use `uninitialized_value_construct` although it would have been more consistent to call `uninitialized_default_construct` when possible.

Containers use neither. Containers construct objects via their allocators. Unfortunately, `allocator_traits<...>::construct` takes an arbitrary series of parameters. Passing no parameters is ambiguous between default initialization and value initialization. Which one gets used is up to the allocator, but there is no way to select which one via the parameter list. The default `allocator_traits::construct` will use value initialization, and it will always do so for all types.

> the current behavior could have been mimicked with `std::vector<double>(100, {})`

Even ignoring the backwards compatibility issues as well as the stuff I just said about allocators, that constructor means "default construct a `double` and then copy that `double`'s value into 100 elements one at a time." So it would not be "the current behavior".

Comment: I think you got my point about the ambiguity between default and value initialization regardless of my inaccuracies. My second point was that for a *normally behaved* T, a possible way to disambiguate could have been to use vector<T>(100), vs. vector<T>(100, {}), at least in c++11.  In the sense that copying a value initialized value to all the elements is the same as value initializing all the elements for such T.

Comment: @alfC: And how would `vector` know that you used `{}` instead of `T{}` or some `T` lvalue? Also, it doesn't matter if `T` is "normally behaved" or not; copying a value 100 times is a different operation from default constructing a value 100 times. Plus, there are `T`s which are default constructible but non-copyable; how do you value-initialize them in a world where no parameters means default constructible?

Comment: You are right, there is no way to distinguish in the current language and copy-value initialization is the only valid interpretation then. But at least there is a syntactic combination that would imply default initialization. Perhaps with some new protocol in the language, default initialization could be eventually informed through the container constructor interface. For example, if we ever have "regular-`Void`", one could say `vector<T>(100, Void{})` for default initialization.